# add php shortcode in return function

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I have this part of code:

```
return '<img class="myimage '.$text_color.' '.$horizontal.$slide_fitscreen.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" '.$slide_desc.' />';
```

What I want to do is to return also  a php shortcode but not inside the `<img>`, because my shortcode generates a `<a>` element so I need to return it after the **img**

this is my shortcode:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[gallery]'); ?>
```

How can I make this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean something like:

```
return '<img class="myimage '.$text_color.' '.$horizontal.$slide_fitscreen.'" src="'.$image.'" alt="" '.$slide_desc.' />'.do_shortcode('[gallery]');
```

Comment: Not really working for me. I receive something like this: `Error (Parseerror): Syntax Error Unexpected Token <` but I guess is from my website not from your code